# How to load a variable into .search

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I am pulling a url, then transforming it to uppercase. I would like to load that variable into  a .search function to filter results.

This is what I have so far, but it is not working correctly:

```
$(function() {
    var search_name = location.search;
    var ucSearch = search_name.toUpperCase();

    if (search_name.search("airports")  > 0) {
        $("div.more a:contains("+ ucSearch +")").addClass("active");
    }

});
```

I think this might just be a syntax issue.

I guess ultimately I would want something like this:

```
$(function() {
   var search_name = location.search;
   var ucSearch = search_name.toUpperCase();

   if (search_name.search("+ ucSearch +")  > 0) {
       $("div.more a:contains("+ ucSearch +")").addClass("active");
   }
});
```

That way it matches up the variable in the url with the variable that is in the anchor html.

UPDATE:

Here is my html

```
<div class="more">
<ul>
  <a class="static" href="#">ALL</a>
  <li><a class="static" href="#">AIRPORTS</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

So I would like the jquery to grab the url and match that url text with the html text in the anchor tag. In this instance "AIRPORTS". The reason I would like to make it a bit more fluid is, what it there were to anchor tags, "AIRPORTS" and "GARAGES". Then it could match what was passed to the url with the corresponding anchor tag and add the "active" class.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DCyJq/)

the url is site/?type=AIRPORTS

Comment: Can you provide some of your HTML so we can see why your function may not be working? Try putting up the javascript and HTML on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Given the use of your if statement I think you'll be better to check that it `!= -1` or that `>= 0` as the string is zero based and if the first occurance is 0 it will fail.

Comment: Do you have a `String.prototype.search` function defined somewhere? where is `search_name.search(...)` coming from?

Comment: Why are your link hrefs `#` and not the actual url `/?type=AIRPORTS`?
Fixing this would solve your problems.

Comment: value of `location.search` needs to be parsed to remove "?type="...show some html

Comment: @iambriansreed - I was thinking that the :contains is looking for html text and not html element data so it would not matter. After further testing this still does not solve the problem.

Comment: @BradChristie - The idea was to search the url for the string, in this case "Airports" which would return true and add the class accordingly. There may be some issues with my logic then?

Comment: So does this mean the syntax for passing a value to the search is correct? I just need to adjust the logic and remove the extraneous url text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

provided that [`window.location.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) will get you the GET query string (in your example, this would contain `?type=AIRPORTS`) we need to start with filtering this to only get the search term. A **very** primitive way is to just use [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr). e.g.

```
var term = window.location.search.substr('?type='.length);
```

now `term` contains `AIRPORTS`. To ensure it's capitalized, we can call [`ToUpperCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) atop this. e.g.

```
var term = window.location           // "http://somesite.com/?type=AIRPORTS"
           .search                   // "?type=AIRPORTS"
           .substr('?type='.length)  // "AIRPORTS"
           .toUpperCase();           // "AIRPORTS"
```

Now, move on to jQuery and find all links with this search term in it and set their class to active:

```
$('div.more a:contains("' + term + '")').addClass('active');
```

And, all together:

```
$(function(){ // document.ready
  var term = window.location.search.substr('?type='.length).toUpperCase();
  $('div.more a:contains("' + term + '")').addClass('active');
});
```